# git - show all the differences on merging

Tags: git

commit structure

```
A
|\
| C (master)
|
B (origin/master)
```

contents of file on `A`

```
1 apple
2 banana
3 coffee
```

contents of file on `B`

```
1 apple
2 ball
3 coffee
4 doll
```

contents of file on `C`

```
1 apple
2 banana
3 coffee
4 dirt
```

If I merge `C` with `B` to push to remote server
the generated file will be like this

```
1 apple
2 ball
3 coffee
>>>>>> C
4 dirt
====== 
4 doll
<<<<<< B
```

But I want to show all changes like this

```
1 apple
>>>>> C
2 banana
=====
2 ball
<<<<< B
3 coffee
>>>>>> C
4 dirt
====== 
4 doll
<<<<<< B
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markers `<<<<<<`, `=======`, and `>>>>>>>` are used to indicate the conflicts involved in a `git merge` (roughly speaking, a conflict occurs when a given line has been concurrently modified in the two branches considered).

Regarding your question, according to the documentation of [git merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) it does not seem possible to do exactly (syntactically) what you mean, because the conflict markers show up only in case of conflict (hence their name).

However, you can get the information you want by using the [git diff](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) command. Here is what you can do *before doing the merge*:

```
git diff B..C  # or what amounts to the same, git diff origin/master..master

diff --git a/file b/file
index e96d86d..258f327 100644
--- a/file
+++ b/file
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 1 apple
-2 ball
+2 banana
 3 coffee
-4 doll
+4 dirt
```

Finally just FYI, this doc explains the typical workflow to follow in case of conflict:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_how_to_resolve_conflicts

> After seeing a conflict, you can do two things:
>
> - Decide not to merge. The only clean-ups you need are to reset the index file to the `HEAD` commit [...] and to clean up working
>     tree changes made by [the merge attempt]; `git merge --abort` can be used for
>     this.
> - Resolve the conflicts. Git will mark the conflicts in the working tree. Edit the files into shape and `git add` them to the index. Use
>     `git commit` or `git merge --continue` to seal the deal.
>     The latter command checks whether there is a (interrupted)
>     merge in progress before calling git commit.

Hoping this helps